# Setting button to be Visible and invisible depending on current view

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have hierarchy like this.

```
<Alloy>
   <Window>
      <View id="titlebar">
         <Button id="home" title="Home" />
         <Label id="title" />
      </View>
      <View id="changing_view">
          /**** This view changes everytime ******/
      </View> 
   </Window>
</Alloy>
```

I have only one window through out my application and I create Controllers and replace the view in my window with that controller's view.

My titlebar view is present all the time and it has Home button. I want to hide the home button in the home view and in the rest of the views, I want to display it.

How do I check if the current view is home view or not?

Comment: You need to provide some more code showing how you are updating your views in controller.

Comment: As @Dragon mentioned below , you have to use hide/show methods of button. And to address problem of **"if its the home view or not"** you can have a boolean value in your controller , which will be initially **false** and when you change the view from controller change the boolean value to **true** and finally create an method which check if this boolean value was true or false , so that the button can be displayed accordingly.

BTW it just an opinion , you must provide more code.

Answer (score 1):

you can [hide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-method-hide) the button in the controller using its id. and later can [show](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-method-show) it, with some other view.

Comment: as @Dragon mentioned you have to use hide/show methods of button.